# Cannot Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I have a desktop PC, a Dual Core 3.4ghz & 2GB of Ram. Hard Disk is 250GB & is partitioned. When I proceed with the installation, I can't find any drive or partition in the Partition list. Therefore I cannot complete the installation.
I also already have Windows 7 on the PC but while installing Ubuntu, i don't get the prompt that there is another OS present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can add screenshots in the comments, but you can edit your question to add those.

Comment: Make sure that windows is shut down completely (i.e. no hibernation, no standby, quick start-up disabled). To achieve this press and hold shift key then select shut-down.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're installing, I suspect from a LiveCD (or USB) and you're not launching the installer from within Windows? If you do, reboot your computer from the USB or CD with the LiveCD content.

Ubuntu should see any free partitions, whether they're formatted in FAT or NTFS and should suggest to use the available space.
If you're not seeing any of these options, go back to windows and remove the partitions that you created for Linux. Leave the space available as untreated space, so no additional partitions or formatting, just 'free space'.
Try to reboot again with your LiveCD and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: I am Installing from a USB Pendrive

Comment: i added some links of the screenshots..maybe you could have a look

Comment: @RJKHR What happens if you click on the + or change button in pic #3?
The installer actually sees that you have enough space available, but you don't have any partitions / mount points selected in screen #3.

Comment: @RJKHR I just checked in a VM... you're missing a picture where Ubuntu asks you to use the free space, erase the complete disk or do something else.
If you select to use the free available space, ubuntu will automatically partition as it sees fit. You chose however to do something else, which brings you to this screen. You will have to set up your partitions yourself (with the +/-/change buttons).
Since you don't seem to familiar with the installation of Ubuntu, I advise you to let Ubuntu choose everything for you.

If you don't see necessary options, re-download and do the MD5 checksum first

Comment: Actually in the installation process, there was a step missing, where the installation asks you to choose whether to install ubuntu alongside windows or to erase everything or try something else. I was unable tonsee this yesterday. But when I tried today, with the same usb pen, I got this step & was able to complete the installation. Thanx for your kind help.

Comment: Cheers, please close the thread as solved if your problem is resolved. Upvoting can also help others who are looking for a solution for the same problem.